# Read Text File and Output Multiple Lines to a Textbox 

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, textbox, while-loop

I'm trying to read a text file with multiple lines and then display it in a textbox. The problem is that my program only reads one line. Can someone point out the mistake to me?

```
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO

Public Class Form1

    Private BagelStreamReader As StreamReader
    Private PhoneStreamWriter As StreamWriter
    Dim ResponseDialogResult As DialogResult

    Private Sub OpenToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
            ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OpenToolStripMenuItem.Click

        'Dim PhoneStreamWriter As New StreamWriter(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)

        'Is file already open
        If PhoneStreamWriter IsNot Nothing Then
            PhoneStreamWriter.Close()
        End If

        With OpenFileDialog1
            .InitialDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory
            .FileName = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
            .Title = "Select File"
            ResponseDialogResult = .ShowDialog()
        End With

        'If ResponseDialogResult <> DialogResult.Cancel Then
        '    PhoneStreamWriter = New StreamWriter(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        'End If

        Try
            BagelStreamReader = New StreamReader(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
            DisplayRecord()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("File not found or is invalid.", "Data Error")
        End Try  
    End Sub

    Private Sub DisplayRecord()

        Do Until BagelStreamReader.Peek = -1
            TextBox1.Text = BagelStreamReader.ReadLine()
        Loop

        'MessageBox.Show("No more records to display.", "End of File")
        'End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub SaveToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
            ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveToolStripMenuItem.Click

        With SaveFileDialog1
            .InitialDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory
            .FileName = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
            .Title = "Select File"
            ResponseDialogResult = .ShowDialog()
        End With

        PhoneStreamWriter.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text)
        With TextBox1
            .Clear()
            .Focus()
        End With
        TextBox1.Clear()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
            ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click

        Dim PhoneStreamWriter As New StreamWriter(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        PhoneStreamWriter.Close()
        Me.Close()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Here is a sample textfile:

> Banana nut
>   Blueberry
>   Cinnamon
>   Egg
>   Plain
>   Poppy Seed
>   Pumpkin
>   Rye
>   Salt
>   Sesame seed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably only getting the last line in the file, right?  Your code sets TextBox1.Text equal to BagelSteramReader.ReadLine() every time, overwriting the previous value of TextBox1.Text. Try `TextBox1.Text += BagelStreamReader.ReadLine() + '\n'`

Edit: Though I must <strike>steal</strike> agree with Hans Passant's commented idea on this;  If you want an more efficient algorithm, File.ReadAllLines() even saves you time and money...though I didn't know of it myself.  Darn .NET, having so many features...

Comment: This isn't the correct answer, it gets murderously slow when the file gets big.  Use TextBox1.Text = BagelStreamReader.ReadToEnd() and omit the loop.  File.ReadAllText() is better.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a program to both write to and read from a text file. To write the lines of a list box to a text file I used the following code:

```
Private Sub txtWriteToTextfile_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtWriteToTextfile.Click

    Dim FileWriter As StreamWriter

        FileWriter = New StreamWriter(FileName, False)

        ' 3. Write some sample data to the file.
        For i = 1 To lstNamesList.Items.Count
            FileWriter.Write(lstNamesList.Items(i - 1).ToString)
            FileWriter.Write(Chr(32))
        Next i

        FileWriter.Close()

End Sub
```

And to read and write the contents of the text file and write to a multi-line text box (you just need to set the multiple lines property of a text box to `true`) I used the following code. I also had to do some extra coding to break the individual words from the long string I received from the text file.

```
Private Sub cmdReadFromTextfile_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdReadFromTextfile.Click
    Dim sStringFromFile As String = ""
    Dim sTextString As String = ""
    Dim iWordStartingPossition As Integer = 0
    Dim iWordEndingPossition As Integer = 0
    Dim iClearedTestLength As Integer = 0

    Dim FileReader As StreamReader


        FileReader = New StreamReader(FileName)

        sStringFromFile = FileReader.ReadToEnd()

        sTextString = sStringFromFile

        txtTextFromFile.Text = ""

        Do Until iClearedTestLength = Len(sTextString)

            iWordEndingPossition = CInt(InStr((Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(sTextString, Len(sTextString) - iWordStartingPossition)), " "))

            txtTextFromFile.Text = txtTextFromFile.Text & (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Mid(sTextString, iWordStartingPossition + 1, iWordEndingPossition)) & vbCrLf

            iWordStartingPossition = iWordStartingPossition + iWordEndingPossition

            iClearedTestLength = iClearedTestLength + iWordEndingPossition

        Loop

        FileReader.Close()


End Sub
```